# How to Create new div for each loop

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, loops

I am using asp.net with c# with Master Page. I was trying to create new div for each loop in the while to be able to make the designee as i want. Is there any way that i can do this Or is there any other way to do if from my aspx.cs only?

aspx.cs :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Response.Write("<div id=test  >");

                    Response.Write(Reader.GetString(3)+" ");
                    Response.Write(Reader.GetString(10) + "<br />");
                    Response.Write("<a href='Info.aspx?param=" + Reader.GetString(0) + "' target='_blank'>" + "More..." + "</a>");

                    Response.Write( "<br />");
                    Response.Write("");
                    Response.Write("</div>");

                    //TextBox1.Text = Reader.GetString(3);
                    //TextBox2.Text = Reader.GetString(10);

                }
}
```

aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainDesigne.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MobilePageRouteDoc.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.MobilePageRoteDoc" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>

    <link href="Assets/Css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </telerik:RadDropDownList>

    <div id="test">



    </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: What problem you have here

Comment: Why not use databinding controls such as `Repeater` or `DataList`. Make your life easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign your `<div id="test">` attribute `runat="server"` like this:

```
<div runat="server" id="test">
```

Then you can access it in your code behind:

```
test.InnerHtml = "your html here";
```

So basically first create your html(the multiple divs) in a loop, then add it to the 'test' div. Also I'd suggest you keep id of every element you create in your loop unique and don't forget to add double quotes... `id="test1"`, `id="test2"`, Here is your modified code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string html = "";
     int i = 0;
     while (Reader.Read())
     {    
         html+= "<div id=\"test" + i +  "\">";    
         html+= Reader.GetString(3) + " ";
         html+= Reader.GetString(10) + "<br />";
         html+= "<a href='Info.aspx?param=" + Reader.GetString(0) + "' target='_blank'>" + "More..." + "</a>";    
         html+=  "<br />";
         html+= "</div>";
         i++;
     }
     test.InnerHtml = html;
}
```

Comment: what if is id="test[i]" how i can access them? from css? can you give an example?

Comment: if you want to reference those divs you generate in your loop from css, it's better to assign them a class: `class="testClass" ` and and css: `.testClass { background: red;}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `<div>` you may follow this using `HtmlGenericControl` which can generate html

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl();
div.ID = "AnyDivID";
div.TagName = "div";
div.Attributes["class"] = "YourClassName";
div.InnerText = string.Format("Inner text= {0} ;", "YourInnerText");
form1.Controls.Add(div);
```